# Avellaneda-Stoikov empirical estimation verification

Tags: high-frequency, market-making

The solution of the model contains constant: $k = \alpha K$, it relates to: (i) probability of getting a fill ($\alpha$) and (ii) market impact ($K$).

**Estimating (i)**. The author proposes that the market order sizes follow a power law distribution:

$$f(x)^Q \propto x^{-1-\alpha}$$

So no problem estimating this.

**Estimating (ii)**. There are two equations of interest here:

$$\Delta p \propto \ln Q \tag{11}$$

$$\begin{align} \lambda (\delta) &= \Lambda \mathbb{P} [\Delta p > \delta] \\ &= \Lambda  \mathbb{P}[\ln Q > K \delta] \\ &= \Lambda \mathbb{P} [Q > \exp \left( K \delta \right)] \\ &= \Lambda \int_{\exp (K \delta)}^{\infty} x^{-1-\alpha} dx \\ &= A \exp \left( -k \delta \right) \end{align} \tag{12}$$

According to the above two:

Line 1 in (12) says $\Delta p > \delta$, but we know that $\Delta p = c \ln Q$, therefore we can re-write:

$$\begin{align} \mathbb{P} [\Delta p > \delta] &= \mathbb{P} [c \ln Q > \delta] \\ &= \mathbb{P} [\ln Q > \frac{1}{c} \delta] \end{align}$$

Therefore, $K = \frac{1}{c}$, the inverse of the proportionality constant that we find in relation $\Delta p \propto \ln Q$.

Is this correct? (The estimation of $K$).

Note:
I am aware of Sophie Laruelle's paper. But, unfortunately, I do not know French.

**Super Note:**
My understanding of [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36073/how-does-one-calibrate-lambda-in-a-avellaneda-stoikov-market-making-problem) answer relating to Sophie's paper:

**Definitions**:

- $t_0$ - start time (this is the start time point in the interarrival time slots in a Poisson Process). Simply put, if you get hit, that is a new time: $t_1$, which becomes your new start time.
- $\delta P$ - distance of your order from the mid price. If the mid price is \$100, and your bid is at \$85, then this quantity is \$15. Same for asks, obviously.
- $P^m (t) $ - is your mid price at time $t$.

**Procedure:**

- Record start time: $t_0$ and corresponding mid price: $P^m(t_0)$ at this time.
- Record the time $t_1$ when the bid/ask is hit and the $\delta P$s. The reason I have added plural "s" ending in there is because you might get hit at a number of levels. An example is asked for here. This is your order book (OB):

```
|--- qty ---| --- size --- |
asks
 $105        10
 $104         5
bids
 $100         6
 $99          5
```

Imagine a market order comes in that eats 8 units on the bid size (so it was a market sell). You record the change in price, $\delta P = \$102 - \$100 = \$2$ at first level and the corresponding time of this trade, $t_1$. You also record $\delta P = \$102 - \$99 = \$3$ at the same time, $t_1$ (in this case). If there was a market order that only took portion of the best ask/bid, or full best ask/bid and did not go deeper, we would only collect a single $\delta P$ with its corresponding $t$. Note that you can define the point at which the order is hit differently, this is up to you.
- You now have time lengths and corresponding sizes. [Interarrival times in a Poisson Process](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_1_2_basic_concepts_of_the_poisson_process.php) are exponential:

$$\mathbb{P}[X_1 > t] = \mathbb{P}\left[ \texttt{no arrival in time (0, t]} \right]= e^{-\lambda t} $$

- So now for each bucket of price changes like: $[\$1, \$1.5]$ i.e. all of the $\delta P$ that are between 1 and 1.5 bucks, you have a list of interarrival times: $[0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 1.1]$ in seconds. Fit the above exponential distribution to each data bucket to obtain some empirical estimate of $\lambda$.
- You now have figure 1 from Sophie's paper. Well done.

**Problems ahead:**

- What now? So the question is, if you fit the regression to this, what is your $k$, what is your $A$?
- **Not so important**. What is this equation referring to, what is $P_1$, what is $P_2$, what is $P$:

$$k = \mathbb{E}_{P1,P2}\left(\frac{\log\lambda(\Delta P1) - \log(\lambda(\Delta P2)}{\Delta P1 - \Delta P2}\right),\quad A=\mathbb{E}_{P}(\lambda(\Delta P) \exp k \Delta P)$$

Comment: This post might help you make sense of her paper: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36073/how-does-one-calibrate-lambda-in-a-avellaneda-stoikov-market-making-problem

Comment: I have seen it, but I can't make much of it. For example, what is $P_1$ and $P_2$ quoted in the expectation of $k$, what is $P$ quoted in the expectation of $A$.

Comment: ok, I think I understand what he is saying there. But not fully. So I will write my understanding in my question above. Hopefully, someone can have a look at it.

Comment: Full disclosure: I haven't used this yet, but my understanding of the process on a very high level, is that you're recording the amount of time it takes for the market to hit a given price level, some number of ticks away from the current price. You then turn that into a probability of being filled at that many ticks away. Then you do many such samples, at different number of ticks, then you plot them in a graph and do a regression to find A and k.

Comment: yup. that is my understanding too from that post you linked me up with. But what is A and what is k in that regression, though?

Comment: I think A and k are just the coefficients of the exponential curve you've graphed, aren't they?

Comment: @wildbunny think you are right

Comment: Shall I add the full thing as an answer?

Comment: go ahead. Thanks

Comment: Does one estimate these coefficients over multiple time frames? E.g. what the arrival rate looks like on multiple days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post updates correctly address most of the problem.

The key is producing a graph like the one in [Sophie's paper](http://events.chairefdd.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/CAHIER_MICRO_1.pdf), once you have that you can do a regression to find $A$ and $k$ in

$$
\lambda(δ) = Ae^{(-kδ)}\,
$$

Intuitively, what you are graphing is a realisation of the above equation, so all you need to do is determine the coefficients.

**edit: I started with a log-linear regression and although it seemed ok at first, it was very poor for small tick sizes, it might actually be better to use the other method, which is**

$$k = \left(\frac{\log(\lambda(δ2) / \lambda(δ1))}{δ2 - δ1}\right),\quad A=\lambda(δ1) e^{(kδ1)}$$

**Where δ1 and λ(δ1) are tick value 1 and rate value 1, so you're essentially just building an exponential curve guaranteed to pass through the values corresponding to the two ticks you arbitrarily pick.**

Some things to watch out for:

1) If you record a fill when the next price level gets hit, you're not recording fill rates, but jump rates

2) The fill rates must be decreasing with $δ$ otherwise the regression wont make any sense and you'll get bad values out.

3) $k$ must be positive, so you'll need to negate it if you do a log level regression

4) What you're recording here is essentially *historical* alpha, which may or may not be useful in any way for predicting what the market is going to do, rather than what it has done.