# Finding the trading intensity - Avellaneda Market Making

Tags: market-making, quants

Where does the K term come from in Avellaneda's description of finding the probability an order gets filled.
Please see the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It is a consequence of (direct) proportionality from equation (2.10):

Equation (2.10) states that the change in price ($\Delta p)$ is proportional to the logarithm of the market order size $Q$:

$$
\Delta p \propto \ln(Q).
$$

From the definition of **[direct proportionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Direct_proportionality)**, $\Delta p$ is directly proportional to  $\ln(Q)$ if there exists a non-zero constant $c$ such that:

$$
\Delta p = c \cdot\ln(Q)
$$
where $c$ is known as the proportionality constant. Replacing $\Delta p$ with $c \cdot\ln(Q)$, dividing with $1/c$ on both sides and setting $1/c = K$, yields the result of the second equation in the derivation:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\Delta p > \delta\right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(\ln(Q) \cdot c > \delta\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\ln(Q) > \frac{1}{c} \delta\right)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\ln(Q) > K \delta\right).
\end{align*}

A discussion regarding estimation of the model can be found **[here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44867/avellaneda-stoikov-empirical-estimation-verification?rq=1)**.

Comment: Basically I need to fit 1/c to make deltaP proportional to c*ln(Q), based on historical data?

Comment: @OscarMorales You would need to fit the end result of the equation ie. $\lambda(\delta)=A \exp(-k \delta)$, with $k$ and $A$ be defined as above. You then try to estimate the params in this equation, $\alpha$, $K$, $\Lambda$ (AFAIK).  I answer the question of where $K$ originates from, which might be from the definition of proportionality. Remember that 1/c is still a constant (for $c$ being a constant) and can be redefined as $K$ to fit the premise of the above equation. I've only read the paper and never tried to fit the model. Therefore, I don't have much insight into this premise.

Comment: Got it this makes sense, thank you.